# How to speed up the deployment to a local glassfish instance?

Tags: deployment, windows-7, glassfish-3

It is very cumbersome to restart the (local running) application server manually every time I want to redeploy an application. Manually copying the EAR to the autodeploy folder works (most of the time), but I still have to navigate to the EAR, copy it, navigate to the autodeploy folder and post there.

Is there a nice way to improve on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created a context menu for *.war and *.ear files. It copies them to autodeploy. Save this to a *.reg file and activate the menu via double click on the file.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.war]
@="war_auto_file"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ear]
@="war_auto_file"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\war_auto_file\shell\deploy2GF\command]
@="cmd /c \"copy \"%1\" C:\\gf_domain\\autodeploy ""
```